# Reading an array populate it and keep reading it

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have the following code:

```
for account in accounts_list:   
    if not checked_accounts_list.has_key(account):
        response = send_request("example/path", {"account_id":account, "page_size":50})
        get_total(response, "accounts", "account_id", **accounts_list**, account)
        checked_accounts_list[account] = True
```

accounts_list is an array which holds 184 results. Inside that loop there is a 
call to a function called "get_total", which expects a few arguments, one of those arguments is passing the same array which is currently being iterated on (highlighted in bold)

I am having a few issues and I believe this is caused due to the fact accounts_list 
expands while i iterate over it.

Bottom line is, How do I keep reading accounts_list while it keeps expanding ?

Comment: which issues do you have? please be specific

Comment: also, why do you retrieve the account for the second time if it's already in the list? are you sure that your logic is correct?

Comment: Is `accounts_list` an actual `list`, or a `dict` as `checked_accounts_list` is?  A `list` can be iterated over as it is appended to, but a `dict` cannot.  It looks like you might actually want something more like a processing queue then a registry of all accounts.  Where does `accounts_list` come from, and can you change how it is formatted or loaded?

Comment: accounts_list is initialized as accounts_list = [] & accounts_list is controlled by me so, yes I can change it.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over a different copy of the list:

```
for account in list(accounts_list):
```

This will iterate over the original items in `accounts_list`, but none of the news ones added while iterating through the loop.

If you wish to also iterate over items added while iterating through the loop, then:

```
while accounts_list:
   account = accounts_list.pop(0)
```

---

For example,

```
def get_total(account, accounts_list):
   accounts_list.append(2*account)

accounts_list = [1]
while accounts_list:
   account = accounts_list.pop(0)
   print(account)
   get_total(account, accounts_list)
```

yields

```
1
2
4
8
16
...
```

Comment: I'm not following, can you show me a complete code that iterates over accounts_list and keeps reading it while it is expanding ?